# How to Dispaly Saved Percentage before price in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hope you all are doing good.

I am trying to add Saved Percentage to woocommerce prices

"eg: 18%"

and I manage to add this but the thing is I want it to show before the price but it displays after the price. any help will be highly appreciated thanks

here is the code which i am using right now:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'woocommerce_saved_sales_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_saved_sales_price( $price, $product ) {
if ( 'simple' === $product->get_type() ) {
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    if ($percentage == "100") {
        return $price;
        } else {
            return $price . sprintf( __('<span class="saved-money">-%s</span>', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );
        }
    }
}
```

Price is currently showing like this: Regular Price + Current Price + Saved Percentage

**However, I want it to be like: Saved Percentage + Regular Price + Current Price**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is controlling the position of the percentage:

```
return $price . sprintf( __('<span class="saved-money">-%s</span>', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );
```

All you need to do is reverse the order. Put `$price` last.

```
return sprintf( __('<span class="saved-money">-%s</span>', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' ) . $price;
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother it fixes the issue